# Subsetting dataframes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a basic function in R that will take a zipcode and output the county, but it's not working for some reason. Every time I try a zipcode, it just outputs the entire original dataframe, not a single county name. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(httr) 
zipcodeData <- content(GET('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scpike/us-state-county-zip/master/geo-data.csv'), type = 'text/csv')

zipCaseGraph<- function(zipcode) {
  tbl.Countycases <- subset(zipcodeData, zipcode==sprintf("%s", zipcode)) 
  return(tbl.Countycases$county)                          
}
```

Comment: One suggestion is to use `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv` would be more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need `sprintf`.
- Don't use the same variable name as your column name.
- Passing dataframe in the function is a good practice.

```
zipCaseGraph<- function(data, zip) {
  tbl.Countycases <- subset(data, zipcode == zip) 
  return(tbl.Countycases$county)                          
}

zipCaseGraph(zipcodeData, 35004)
#[1] "St. Clair"
zipCaseGraph(zipcodeData, 35005)
#[1] "Jefferson"
```

Comment: How about if I want to use sprintf() later on in my code-- it doesn't really work for this URL :   url <- sprintf("https://knowi.com/api/data/ipE4xJhLBkn8H8jisFisAdHKvepFR5I4bGzRySZ2aaXlJgie?entityName=County%207%20day%20growth%20rates&exportFormat=csv&c9SqlFilter=select%20*%20where%20County%20like%20 %s %20County%20AND%20State%20like%20 %s", countyZip, stateZip)

Comment: `zipCaseGraph` function is used only to subset data, right? If you want to download data from some url you can use `sprintf` there to construct the URL.